# Assert that element does not exists with FindById notation

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I'm writing tests for a system that shows a Popup on the first login but doesn't on the subsequent logins.

Currently my code is something like this:

**PopupPage**

```
class PopupPage extends BasePage {
  @FindById(id="closeBtn")
  private WebElement closeButton;

  public boolean isDisplayed(){
    //Throws an error when the popup isn't displayed because the popup isn't in the DOM.
    return closeButton.isDisplayed();       
   }
}
```

This is very similar [to this question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3481/quicker-way-to-assert-that-an-element-does-not-exist/24329#24329), but I don't want to repeat the selector that is already present in the FindById notation.

So how do I assert that the element is on page or not ? (Ideally I would like to have some method coming from the WebElement like `closeButton.isStale()` or something like this.

Comment: You shouldn't assert the non presence of an element since you'll get a false positive if the selector where to no longer match the targeted element. Instead assert the text in the page or try to perform an action which will be prevented by the popup and assert the exception.

Comment: Yes, but I should check if the element exists on the DOM, otherwise I'll get a `NoSuchElementException` when trying to check the text

Comment: You won't get any exception by reading the text from the container which contains (or not) the popup.

Comment: Ah, now I do understand what you mean. It may work, but its not very elegant solution :/. Peter answer works too, but it doesn't seems right

Comment: The goal here is to prevent regression when the code changes, not to be elegant. Rather than trying to find a technical shortcut, you should try to implement a test from a user perspective to validate a usage.

Comment: My goal is to be able to check that the element is not visible that is easily undernstandable. I could write: `driver.findElements(By.id("closeBtn")).size() == 0` but then I would be duplicating the selector.

Answer (score 2):

In a page object model, all defined elements are initialized to null using the pagefactory.

If an element does not exist in the DOM, then it will remain null when you refer to it.

Therefore, simply check your element for a null value.

```
/**
 * Is the element displayed?
 * @author Bill Hileman
 * @param element - a web element
 * @param locator - a verbal description of the element for logging purposes
 * @return Boolean true if displayed, false if not displayed or null
 */
public Boolean isDisplayed(WebElement element, String locator) {

    Boolean passFail = false;

    try {
        if (element.isDisplayed())
            passFail = true;
    } catch (NullPointerException | NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to locate element '" + locator + "'");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to check display status of element '" + locator + "'");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return passFail;

}
```

Comment: Doing this will cause the driver to wait the `implicitlyWait` time before triggering a `NoSuchElementException `.

And the elements are initialized on the Page constructor by the method `PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);`, so they are never null

Comment: That's not how I understand it.  implicit wait never comes into play with pagefactory unless you use AjaxElementLocatorFactory along with it, and then it only comes into play when you try to access the web element.  The code above works properly for me when checking for an element which might not be in the DOM.

Comment: In fact, you simply need to take your existing code and throw a try/catch in there for that specific reason.

Comment: I just tested it: Set the `implicitlyWait` to a absurd value like 200. Check the behavior of your method. It will wait for 200 seconds before the `NoSuchElementException ` is triggered

Comment: Try this, but set the time to whatever you think is appropriate, and please let me know: `PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 15), this);`

Comment: `find_elements()` proposed in my answer will return a list of elements **without waiting** (if present), or returns empty list if none are present. No need to deal with the exceptions either, much cleaner.

Comment: @Peter Masiar, are you sure about that? Last time I checked find_elements waits for at least one element before returning when the implicit wait is set. Anyway the implicit wait as currently designed should no be used nor recommended.

Comment: If you want to specifically check for the existence of element(s) then I agree that findElements is the quickest, cleanest method, however it goes against the entire idea of a page object model.

Comment: @FlorentB. - I am 100% sure that `find_elements()` (please note plural) **does not wait**. `find_element()` (singular) is the one which waits.

Comment: @BillHileman - not sure how and why using `find_elements()` to detect if elements are present or missing is against PageObject design pattern. I am using PageObject and `find_elements()` for few years now, what I am missing?

Comment: I talked myself out of it trying to argue the point in a reply.  I think I either cannot express myself well, or I may just be of a minority opinion.  It's like you can't use a dynamic locator in POM, but there are ways to work around it, and rather than mix two different object models, I just prefer to be consistent.  There is nothing wrong with using exception handling - I simply put my exception handling in a wrapper class so that I can try to cover all bases.  Probably still not being clear, sorry.

Comment: Have you tried something as simple as `if (pageObject.element.equals(null))` ?  I'm also fairly sure that the page object initialization initializes all variables to null - what else could they be initialized to since the actual retrieve/check does not happen until the element is later attempted to be referenced?  I notice no lag whatsoever in my POM's when an object (expectedly) does not exist.

Comment: @Peter Masiar. I just tested with Firefox and Chrome and `find_elements()` (plural) **waits for at least one element** or until timeout to return a result when the implicit wait is set.

Comment: @FlorentB. - oh I see. I never use implicit waits, only explicit, as per best practices, and implicit default is 0. In fact, I never use raw selenium calls, just our custom convenience wrappers (which include explicit wait)  :-) My bad :-(

Comment: @BillHileman - I use dynamic locators all the time (if/when I can figure our any logic in locators). Also, as Python user, I am very pragmatic. I think that empty list instead of exception handling is less lines of code and fits my brain better. Empty list is conveniently false value in Python. I guess we have all set ways/styles in our code. I used to code in Java and C#, but now I cannot do it anymore: too much effort compared with Python :-) Maybe my brains are deficit and cannot handle the complexity.

Answer (score 2):

The method I use is to use `findElements()` and check the `.size()`; zero means gone, any positive number means it's still there.

Also, programming is all about not repeating yourself, so make the selector a variable :)

```
String idOfThing = "closeBtn";
@FindBy(id = idOfThing)
private WebElement closeButton;

if (!doesItExistById(idOfThing)) {
    System.out.println("It vanished!");
}

public boolean doesItExistById(String id) {
    return driver.findElements(By.id(id)).size() > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has find_elements() group of methods which:

- do not wait
- return a matching list, which is empty if no matching elements are found

Please note is is element**s**. I assume Java has similar methods.

isDisplayed() can be used only on a valid located element, it will fail if element is not present.

This approach has additional benefit that you can check for a presence/absence of multiple elements (or elements with no unique locators, like error messages) which might have a name or CSS class but no known unique id.

Comment: Using `find_elements` works, but it doesn't seem the best approach, because then I would need to access the element by the list index, something like this: `closeButton.get(0).isDisplayed()`

Comment: @AndréRoggeriCampos - not sure why `get(0)` is a problem? You have two different problems here: (1) find out if element is present at all (2) if present, if it is displayed.

Comment: Because it doesn't make sense cast the WebElement that is unique as a List, because its not.

Doing so will require to write the `get(0)` (Which is not a problem, but I'm looking for a better solution)

Comment: Although, this solves my problem, I'll wait to see if some other solution is presented, otherwise I'll mark this as my answer

Comment: @AndréRoggeriCampos - you don't need to cast anything as list. `findElements()` will **return a list** and do it **without waiting**. You are used to deal with unique locators, which always wait. I often use `find_elements()` and then loop over returned elements and pick one by other attributes. It gives me flexibility to use more robust locators (which might not be unique). I commend you to wait for other answers, more people should give a chance other timezones to respond :-)

Comment: Yes, but the goal here is to keep using the annotation `FindBy`, otherwise your solution is the way to go !

Comment: @AndréRoggeriCampos - I thought that goal is to establish if elements exists (or not) by *whatever selenium method is the most appropriate for the task*. At least this is how I think when I am reading the library: *which method is best fit for which task at hand*. Of course you can use hammer (findById) as universal tool, but sometimes other tools are better and more convenient :-)

Comment: Yes, I do understand that. I was just trying to be consistent. Tomorrow I'll try to reimplement the WebElement and expose the locator, so I can at least not duplicate the locator.